# How to check if Visualforce page is inline or in standalone window in lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience, inline-visualforce

I'm looking for help on how to figure out if a Visualforce page is opened in a standalone window or is visible as part of the record detail page in lightning experience.

I have a Visualforce page which is included in the detail page for Quote. This page is also opened as standalone page. But, in lightning, I'm not able to figure how to figure out if it is included in detail page or opened as standalone page.

In Salesforce Classic, I was checking `window.self !== window.top`, which works fine. But, in lightning, its not working.

I would like to hear if anyone has any ideas on how to achieve this in lightning.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not open that VF page as a quick-action instead of inline visualfore?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the approach you are suggesting?

Comment: In lightning in VF, can you check for `{!$User.UITheme == 'Theme4d'}`. More info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_useruitheme.htm)